# Sending Image to a Web Server Showing Force close and wait(ANR) in Android

Tags: android, image, upload

I am sending images to a webserver having combined size of 500kbs, but while uploading application shows Activity Not Responding force close and wait. How can I remove this so that the images are uploaded without any interruption?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Without knowing what you have implement, how can we suggest you?

Comment: @Paresh I am sending images and corresponding data by inserting it into array NameValuePair and sending it to server using httppost method. The images are uploaded without any interruption if only 1 to 3 images are send but if images are more it is showing application not responding(web service is made in asp.net)

Answer (score 0):

An Android application runs on the "main" or "UI" thread. Long operations on it cause an ANR.

You need to do the upload in a separate thread.
You might want to use the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class that will help you do that easily.

Comment: Thanx for your instant reply...but I am already sending it in the background thread

Comment: Can you post some code?
What is your main thread doing while the upload happens in the background?